# Ссылка со значением из инпута

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Задача вписать в поле input некий текст, пусть будет "321" и по нажатию "Send" перейти на http://site.ру/add/321/

пробовал так, не получается:

```
<input id="text" type="text" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Send" onClick=self.location="http://site.ру/add/"+document.getElementById("text").value;>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде ошибка: в onClick должна быть строка, которая интерпретируется в JS. т.е.

```
<input id="text" type="text" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Send" onClick="self.location='http://site.ру/add/'+document.getElementById('text').value; return false;">
```